# Como alterar o tamanho da View do Google Map para iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Estou utilizando o Google Map SDK for iOS em um projeto, mas ao usar o serviço por padrão ele cobre toda a tela. Porém preciso ter espaço para adicionar alguns botões na tela.

Como posso redimensionar a view do mapa?

No momento usando o código padrão:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                            longitude:longitude
                                                                 zoom:17];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;


    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    marker.title = nomeCliente;
    marker.snippet = @"Detalhes";
    marker.map = mapView_;
```

Com este código fica deste jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas preciso que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O MKMapView somente está na imagem para exemplificar. Eu removi assim que fiz o print da tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esta questão fiz as seguintes alterações no código:

```
// Criei uma nova posição e novas dimensões
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300);


    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                            longitude:longitude
                                                                 zoom:17];

    // Utilizei a nova posição e dimensão e usei para alterar os valores de mapView_ 
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:rect camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;


    //self.view = mapView_;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView_];

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
    marker.title = nomeCliente;
    marker.snippet = @"Detalhes";
    marker.map = mapView_;
```

Embora eu mesmo tenha conseguido resolver, de maneira rápida, fiz a pergunta pois ja tinha feito outros testes e modificações.